# Android - can't access strings with R.string

Tags: java, android

I am have trouble accessing a string I stored in strings.xml and don't know why.

**res/values/strings.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="FileBrowser">FileBrowser</string>
    <string name="menu_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="up_one_level">..</string>
    <string name="current_dir">.</string>
</resources>
```

**Code**

```
this.directoryEntries.add(getString(R.string.current_dir)); //current_dir is not being seen
```

Comment: What error do you get when you build your app?

Comment: Make sure that you have imported your `R`-class and not `android.R`

Comment: Ahh that was it. Thanks Simon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this means you have an error in one of your XML files so it can't rebuild your resources.  Look under the problems tab in Eclipse and you'll probably see an XML issue, could be in any of your XML files, not necessarily in `strings.xml`.

Comment: Ahh yes that was a problem too so there were actually 2 issues. Thanks guy.

Answer (score 2):

Check that you did not add the following import by mistake:

```
import android.R
```

It happened to me several times this week.
Delete this line and everything will work as expected.

Comment: Worth noting that if you paste java code into your kotlin project and you confirm the conversion to kotlin, it might auto add this line to your imports.